# Spring Boot Dynamically load authorization URL's with antMatchers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have been trying to develop an application which shall load the authorization URL's from database. This application shall not have any user interface.
When I try to send request's through postman it gives me an error of "403". If I add 
`.antMatchers("/login").permitAll();`
in the top then the application permits all request which is authenticated successfully whether the user have that authorization or not. Below my codes are given

> WebSecurityConfig.cass

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

       http
          .csrf().disable()
          .authorizeRequests() 
          .antMatchers("/login").permitAll();

        //Module List are holding modules which shall provide the URL's and authority names
        List<Module> moduleList = _moduleDAO.getModule();
        for (Module module : moduleList) {
            if(module.getUrl() != null & module.getModuleName() != null) {
                String url = module.getUrl();
                String authority = module.getModuleName();
                String requestType = module.getRequestType();

                if(requestType != null) { 
                    if(requestType == "GET") {
                        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,url).hasAuthority(authority); 
                    }else if(requestType == "POST") {
                        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, url).hasAuthority(authority); 
                    }else if(requestType == "DELETE") {
                        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,url).hasAuthority(authority); 
                    }else if(requestType == "PUT") {
                        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, url).hasAuthority(authority); 
                    } 
                }
                logger.info("-- Adding URL : " +url +" Request Type : "+requestType+" With Authority : " + authority);
            }
        }
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().denyAll().and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }
```

> UserPrinciple.class

```
public class UserPrinciple implements UserDetails{

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    //Get Roles
    if(this.roleList != null) {
        this.roleList.stream().distinct().forEach(role -> {
            if(role != null && role.getRole() != null) {
                String RoleName = "ROLE_"+role.getRole();
                logger.info("#Adding "+RoleName + " to the authority");
                GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(RoleName);
                authorities.add(authority);
            }
        });

        //Get Modules
        if(this.moduleList != null) {
            this.moduleList.forEach(module ->{
                String moduleName = module.getModuleName();
                logger.info("#Adding "+moduleName + " to the authority");

                GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(moduleName);
                authorities.add(authority);
            });
        }
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

In database I have stored these modules as described in the below link:
https://pasteboard.co/JdHgh5W.png

Comment: Did you able to resolve this issue ? I need the same solution as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know why but it appears that the only fault I had done is in the **if condition**. While debugging I have found that my statements under these if condition was not being executed. So I have changed my code statement approach. 
I have just changed this

```
if(requestType == "GET") {
```

into

```
if(requestType.equals("GET")) {
```

It turns out that there was some problem in database too. The request types were not matching in **"if condition"** maybe in database the string was stored in different format. I have copied the request type string (i.e. GET, POST) from the log console of the IDE and pasted into the database columns.

And Everything started to work perfectly now. :V